# What can we infer from (x|y)=(x|z) in a real inner product space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products

$(x|y) = (x|z)$

I think the vectors $y$ and $z$ are parallel to each other.

What else can be said?

Comment: It is not clear what your equation is supposed to mean. Are you saying that $y$ and $z$ are such that $(x|y) = (x|z)$ for **every** $x$, or are you simply saying that there exist $x,y,z$ such that $(x|y) = (x|z)$?

Comment: Yes, i'm simply saying that there exist x,y,z such that ($x$|$y$)=($x$|$z$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are talking about
$$
\langle x,y \rangle=\langle x,z \rangle
$$
being true for any $x,y,z \in (V, \langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle)$, then you can not infer $y$ and $z$ being parallel to each other.
A counterexample would be $V=\mathbb{R}^3$ and $x=(1,0,0)^t, y=(0,1,0)^t$ and $z=(0,0,1)^t$. Even though with the standard inner product
$$
\langle x,y \rangle=1\cdot0+0\cdot1+0\cdot0=0=1\cdot0+0\cdot0+0\cdot1=\langle x,z \rangle
$$
your identity holds, it is obviously not true that $y$ is parallel to $z$.
However, the following holds because of the bilinearity of the inner product:
$$
\langle x,y \rangle=\langle x,z \rangle \Leftrightarrow \langle x,y-z \rangle=0
$$
which means that $x \perp y-z$.

Comment: I get it now. Thank you.

Comment: Not a problem. :)